# What is the well reputed and stable eCommerce framework build on Microsoft asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, e-commerce

Can you please let me know, what is the well reputed and stable eCommerce framework build on Microsoft asp.net MVC? please categorize as opensource and paid licence. Thank you.

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: As per my opinion, nopCommerce is the best choice if you really finding eCommerce platform. It's an open source e-commerce solution that is ASP.NET 4.5 (MVC 5) based with a MS SQL 2008. which has well [support forum](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/) and [documentation](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=983094)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used **nopcommerce** and it is a good framework.

nopCommerce has a wealth of features and capabilities designed to create an online store

http://www.nopcommerce.com/